# searchDelete in Link listed in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Getting stuck in question numbers.

2. insertAfterSearch (searches for a data, if found, insert the new data after the searched node CLUE: 2 parameters)
3. searchDelete (searches for a data, then deletes the node if found, CLUE: 1 parameter)
   Can someone help me to solve this issue.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.nodeValue = data
        self.nodeLink = None
        
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.startNode = None
        

        
    def traverseList(self):
        if self.startNode is None:
            print("List is empty")
        else:
            currentNode = self.startNode
            while currentNode is not None:
                print(currentNode.nodeValue, end = " ")
                currentNode = currentNode.nodeLink
            print("End of Link")
    
    def insertAtEnd(self, data):
        newNode = Node(data)
        if self.startNode is None:
            self.startNode = newNode
        else:
            currentNode = self.startNode
            while currentNode.nodeLink is not None:
                currentNode = currentNode.nodeLink
            currentNode.nodeLink = newNode
    
        
    def searchValue(self, searchData):
        if self.startNode is None:
            print("List is empty")
        else:
            currentNode = self.startNode
            nodeNumber = 1
            while currentNode is not None:
                if currentNode.nodeValue == searchData:
                    print("Found the Data", searchData, "at Node", nodeNumber)
                    return
                else:
                    currentNode = currentNode.nodeLink
                    nodeNumber += 1
            print("Data not found")
            
    def generateLinkedList(self):
        numOfInput = int(input("How many nodes do you want to create: "))
        if numOfInput == 0:
            return
        for currentInput in range(numOfInput):
            print("Node #", currentInput+1, ": ", end ="")
            inValue = int(input("Enter the value for the node: "))
            self.insertAtEnd(inValue)
    
        
        
sampleList = LinkedList()
sampleList.generateLinkedList()
sampleList.traverseList()
sampleList.searchValue(3)
```

https://pastebin.com/b1wGZeMJ

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this by giving the node a method (What we call functions if they are inside an object) to check whether or not it has the searched value.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.nodeValue = data
        self.nodeLink = None

    def find_value(self, value):
        if self.nodeValue == value:
            return self

        elif self.nodeLink == None:
            return None

        else:
            return self.nodeLink.find_value(value)
```

This way you can just ask the first object to find you the value and it will pass it on until it finds that value and the object is handed back the chain to the front so to you it will look like the head will just give you the answer. With this we can then insert and delete objects.

## Insert after search

To insert an object you will need to take the found-objects (parent) link (child) and save it. Then point the parents link to your new object and the objects link to the child. For this I will define a method in the Node that does that:

```
def insert_link(self, value):
    new_child = Node(value)
    old_child = self.nodeLink

    self.nodeLink = new_child
    new_child.nodeLink = old_child
```

Note how this method also creates the new object for you. Now I have also defined a print_node and a print_list function in the Node and the List-Object respectively:

Node:

```
def print_node(self):
    print(self.nodeValue, end = " -> ")

    if self.nodeLink is None:
        print(None)
        return

    self.nodeLink.print_node()
```

List:

```
def print_list(self):
    self.startNode.print_node()
```

Now we can test the insertion:

```
def main():
    sampleList = LinkedList()
    sampleList.generateLinkedList()
    sampleList.print_list()
    sampleList.insertAfterSearch(3, 6)
    sampleList.print_list()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the terminal:

```
$ python3 linked_list.py 
How many nodes do you want to create: 1
Node # 1 : Enter the value for the node: 3
3 -> None
3 -> 6 -> None
```

## Search and Delete

For this we need to find a node and set it's parents link to it's child. The node then should be deleted. I will also do that recursively using the node. For this we will add a method "self-destruct" (because it's cool):

```
def self_destruct(self, parent, value):

    if not self.nodeValue == value:

        if self.nodeLink is None:
            print("Value not found")
            return None

        found_node = self.nodeLink.self_destruct(self, value)
        return found_node
```

In the linked list we will first test if the head will be deleted. If so we just need to reassign the head. If it's not the head we need to start the self-destruct search:

```
def deleteSearch(self, key):

    if self.startNode.nodeValue == key:
        found = self.startNode
        self.startNode = found.nodeLink


    else:
        found = self.startNode.self_destruct(None, key)

    if found is None:
        print("Could not find object")
    else:
        del found # Not really needed because garbage collector, but I don't trust that sourcery.
```

New Main:

```
def main():
    sampleList = LinkedList()
    sampleList.generateLinkedList()
    sampleList.print_list()
    sampleList.deleteSearch(3)
    sampleList.print_list()
```

Will generate:

```
$ python3 linked_list.py 
How many nodes do you want to create: 5
Node # 1 : Enter the value for the node: 1
Node # 2 : Enter the value for the node: 5
Node # 3 : Enter the value for the node: 3
Node # 4 : Enter the value for the node: 2
Node # 5 : Enter the value for the node: 7
1 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -> 7 -> None
1 -> 5 -> 2 -> 7 -> None
```

And deleting the starting node also works:

```
$ python3 linked_list.py 
How many nodes do you want to create: 4
Node # 1 : Enter the value for the node: 3
Node # 2 : Enter the value for the node: 7
Node # 3 : Enter the value for the node: 8
Node # 4 : Enter the value for the node: 9
3 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> None
7 -> 8 -> 9 -> None
```

Because you are new here I would like to note that if an answer solved your solution you should confirm that answer as it gives the answerers more reputation and it makes finding the correct answer easier for other people.

Comment: Hi Rayn, kindly shared me the compile code above. thank you

Comment: That.. is not what I meant. There is a checkmark under the rate-buttons. You as the poster can press that to verify the answer.

Comment: Also compiled in computer science is a term referring to a very specific task.

Comment: i tried to follow your step but i didnt succeed im getting error.

Comment: i just want to ask this file sir linked_list.py